# CDO installation in conda

Tags: python, terminal, netcdf, cdo-climate, grib

I am trying since yesterday to convert a `grib` file to a `netcdf` file (ECMWF dataset). As the grib file has to be interpolated from reduced to regular Gaussian grid before I can apply grib_to_netcdf, I will use `CDO` in my MacOS terminal. However, I cannot install the package in `conda` as I keep getting these messages:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

I have also tried to use jupyter notebook and python (with `xarray`) but since this file is roughly 66 GB, it is taking a long time and the kernel kept dying on me.

Has anyone experienced this before and can give me some advice? With `pip install cdo` it worked but then it's stored in the wrong channel (`pypi` instead of `conda-forge`) and if I try to call a cdo command in the terminal it says it's unknown.

Cheers!

Comment: I recommend switching to using mamba instead of conda. You will not run into these problems. Mambaforge is the best solution in my view https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge

Comment: Note that the pypi Cdo is a python package which calls Cdo. It is not the same thing as the Cdo available on conda forge